# create html field based on js variable value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a property called `results.row` in JS. Using the value of that, I have to create textboxes in html. Suppose the value of `results.row` is 5,then I want to create 5 textboxes in html.

Also, the data to be shown on the textboxes is inside `results.rows.item(i)` . Is it possible to display?

HTML

```
<textbox name="Medicine Name" id="medicine"/>
```

JS

```
    var rows = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    {
    var textbox = document.createElement('input');

    textbox.type = 'text';
    textbox.value = 'value here ' + i;
    document.getElementsByName('medicine')[0].appendChild(textbox);
    }
```

Comment: All of these things are possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: You could use a loop.

Comment: I highly recommended you to use Handlebars JS library. It has unlimited templating possibilities. Visit this site http://www.handlebarsjs.com

Comment: And am I to understand that `results.rows` is an object with a method called `item` that acts like an array accessor?  That's not a very common pattern.  Why not `results.rows[i]` (an array of objects)?

Comment: I tried using document.getElementbyId but I dont know how to implement it for arrays.

Comment: Are you after something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/2pmftcbe/3/)?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu yes some what closer.

Comment: You have document.getElementsByName('medicine')  ,but actual  name="Medicine Name"  .